# While lemmatizing the corpus and splitting and joining it , it shows Word List Corpus Reader not callable error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, lemmatization

My code where I get error goes as follows :

```
import re
corpus = []
for i in range(len(sentences)):
   review = re.sub('[^a-zA-z]', ' ',sentences[i])
   review = review.lower()
   review = review.split()
   review = [lemmatize.lemmatize(word) for word in review if not word in     # getting error 
                                                                           # in this statement  
   set(stopwords('english'))]                                                  
   review = ' '.join(review)  
   corpus.append(review)
```

I am unable to find what Word List Corpus Reader is and not knowing how to use it, just saw this using tutorials. What is the correct syntax and how do I resolve this error?

Comment: Replace `stopwords('english')` with `stopwords.words('english')` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Replace `stopwords('english')` with `stopwords.words('english')` and it will work.
This issue is you're calling `stopwords` which is an object of `WordListCorpusReader` and is not callable. You can call it's method

```
>>> type(stopwords)
<class 'nltk.corpus.reader.wordlist.WordListCorpusReader'>
```

See the code snippet for your case

```
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatize = WordNetLemmatizer()
corpus = []
sentences = [
        "This is sentence one",
        "Moving on to the sentence two"
        ]

for i in range(len(sentences)):
   review = re.sub('[^a-zA-z]', ' ',sentences[i])
   review = review.lower()
   review = review.split()
   review = [lemmatize.lemmatize(word) for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
   review = ' '.join(review)
   corpus.append(review)

print(corpus)
```

Output will be like

```
['sentence one', 'moving sentence two']
```